# How to uninstall Netbeans 6.8 on ubuntu Lucid Lynx (10.04 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, netbeans

I manually installed Netbeans 6.8, by downloading the binary and installing it.

I am now upgrading to Netbeans 6.9, and I want to uninstall the previous version first.

Any tips on how to uninstall Netbeans 6.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this:

Go to the directory where NetBeans was installed (e.g. netbeans-6.8 in /usr/local) and start ./uninstall.sh script.

```
   sudo /usr/local/share/netbeans-6.8/uninstall.sh
```

and in other cases if the jdk is located in another folder (like this one isn't in the netbeans-6.8 folder)

```
sudo /usr/local/share/netbeans-6.8/uninstall.sh --javahome /usr/local/share/jdk1.6.0_05/
```

OR you can read this

http://www.karthikeyanc.com/blog/index.php/2009/12/how-to-uninstall-netbeans-from-ubuntu/

Comment: link has no content

Answer (score 2):

Just run `updatedb` and then `locate uninstall.sh`, then run the correct one.

I personally uninstall both glassfish and netbeans using that same method.

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt find the uninstall.sh file so i used the Synaptic Package Manager, i marked all Netbeans 6.8 components to be removed and voila! simply like that.

Answer (score 1):

In my Ubuntu 10.10, Netbeans `uninstall.sh` is located in the directory `home/userName/netbeans-6.8/`

Run this command to unstall Netbeans:

```
sudo home/userName/netbeans-6.8/uninstall.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unistall netbeans-7.0.1 for Ubuntu by executing this command:

```
sudo sh usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/uninstall.sh
```