# Uninstall software in linux

Tags: linux

If I install on linux netbeans ( or some other program ) with ./netbeans.sh in /usr/local, how I can uninstall netbeans ( or that other program ) ?

Comment: Do you want a general answer or one specific for Netbeans (also see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/161247/how-to-uninstall-netbeans-6-8-on-ubuntu-lucid-lynx-10-04-lts))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one uses package management to install and uninstall packages.

As regarding Netbeans, the official instructions are [here](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/50/install.html#uninstall).

According to this [thread](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/113006-how-do-i-uninstall-netbeans-5-51-ubuntu.html) :

> the uninstaller was in the /opt
>   directory and i had to type sudo `./_uninstal_`

Comment: But I wouldn't recommend this for Java programs like Eclipse, Tomcat or Netbeans. When there are extra plugins installed, all the settings are gone if the package manager installs a new version.

Comment: @Bevor: How does that relate to uninstalling?

Comment: My comment is related to your first sentence. Just as additional information.